# Is there a Vue or Vuetify component that does not render ANY output?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a custom `navMenu` component that I show twice on my page - once across the top, and once hidden in a `v-navigation-drawer` until the screen width gets small enough to show it:

```html
<template>
  <nav>
    <v-app-bar app hide-on-scroll>
      <template #extension v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp">
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-spacer />
            <navMenu :items="menuItems" />
            <v-spacer />
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </template>

      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        @click="toggleDrawer()"
        v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.xs"
      />
      <img id="logo"
             alt="corporate logo"
        src="@/assets/full_logo.svg"
        width="200"
        height="60"
      />
      <v-spacer />
      <h3 class="info--text headline">My Fancy Website</h3>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer app
                         v-model="drawer"
                         v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown">
      <navMenu :items="menuItems" />
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </nav>
</template>
```

**NavMenu.vue**

```html
<template>
    <v-col v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <div v-if="item.children">
        <v-menu transition="slide-y-transition" bottom>
          <template #activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn text v-on="on">{{ item.label }}</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item
              v-for="(child, j) in item.children"
              :key="j"
              router
              :exact="child.exact"
              :to="{ name: child.routeName }"
            >
              <v-list-item-title class="text-capitalize">
                {{ child.label }}
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </v-menu>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <v-btn text router :to="{ name: item.routeName }" :exact="item.exact">
          {{ item.label }}
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </v-col>
</template>
```

...you may have noticed a fatal flaw in my component: you can't iterate on a root element!  Simple enough, wrap it in a `<div />`, right?  **Wrong.**  Wrapping the contents of the template in a `div` really screws up the layout of the menu items - it renders them stacked vertically instead of horizontally - I think the CSS is looking for a direct child or something.

Is there some alternative element that I can use for the template to satisfy the "one root element" edict that doesn't render any output?  Oh, and I tried using the `<template />` element already - you can't use it as a root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close to finding the answer...

Actually, you should put in a `div` container, but then just change the `display` property of the container so the items are still positioned horizontally:

### NavMenu.vue

```js
<template>
  <div style="display: flex"> 
     <v-col v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      ...
```

Comment: This got me 90% of the way, but it borked the _vertical_ layout in the `v-navigation-drawer`, so I added a `flex` prop and pass that in to the template to control flex/unflex.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code below. Essentially, all you need to do is to move the entire `<v-navigation-drawer>` component into your `NavMenu.vue` file and add the additional `drawer` prop. Since the `<v-navigation-drawer` component doesn't actually do much on its own. The `@input` event listener is only so that you can have the parent component update the `drawer` value outside of the child component.

```html
<template>
  <nav>
    <v-app-bar app hide-on-scroll>
      <template #extension v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp">
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-spacer />
            <navMenu :items="menuItems" />
            <v-spacer />
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </template>

      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        @click="toggleDrawer()"
        v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.xs"
      />
      <img id="logo"
             alt="corporate logo"
        src="@/assets/full_logo.svg"
        width="200"
        height="60"
      />
      <v-spacer />
      <h3 class="info--text headline">My Fancy Website</h3>
    </v-app-bar>

    <navMenu
      v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown"
      :drawer="drawer"
      :items="menuItems"
      @navInput="toggleDrawer()"
    />
  </nav>
</template>

NavMenu.vue

<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer app :value="drawer" @input="$emit('navInput')>
    <v-col v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <div v-if="item.children">
        <v-menu transition="slide-y-transition" bottom>
          <template #activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn text v-on="on">{{ item.label }}</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item
              v-for="(child, j) in item.children"
              :key="j"
              router
              :exact="child.exact"
              :to="{ name: child.routeName }"
            >
              <v-list-item-title class="text-capitalize">
                {{ child.label }}
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </v-menu>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <v-btn text router :to="{ name: item.routeName }" :exact="item.exact">
          {{ item.label }}
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </v-col>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      drawer: Boolean,
      items: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => []
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```